# Visual Studio 2022 Couldn't install Microsoft.Net.4.7.1.TargetingPack.Resources,version=4.7.2558.2,language=en-US

Tags: visual-studio

at the end of visual studio 2022 installation from visual studio installer I get this message:

"Couldn't install Microsoft.Net.4.7.1.TargetingPack.Resources".

This is the log

> Package
> 'Microsoft.Net.4.7.1.TargetingPack.Resources,version=4.7.2558.2,language=en-US'
> failed to install.
> Search URL
> https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Net.4.7.1.TargetingPack.Resources;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1625
> Details
> MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.4.7.1.TargetingPack.Resources,version=4.7.2558.2,language=en-US\netfx_471mtpacklp_docredirected.msi,
> Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1
> MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  EXTUI="1"
> Return code: 1625
> Return code details: This installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator.
> Log
> C:\Users\filos\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230920143932_001_Microsoft.Net.4.7.1.TargetingPack.Resources.log
> Impacted workloads
> Game development with Unity (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedGame,version=17.7.33905.399)
> Impacted components
> .NET Framework 4.7.1 targeting pack (Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.TargetingPack,version=17.7.33905.399)
> Visual Studio Tools for Unity (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Unity,version=17.7.33905.399)

Visual studio starts, but it clearly has problems like not suggesting methods of a class or not checking for errors in the code. I am trying to use it with Unity.

I tried starting the app via administrator and also changing values on regedit, in short some tutorials found online, but nothing.